# How to make adjustable height container?

Tags: flutter

I want to make a container that resizes itself to a max height, I've tried adding the boxconstraint, but it keeps stretching out to maxHeight for some reason, how can I avoid that? Positioned is child of stack.

```dart
 Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 200,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 7,
                    offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                  ),
                ],
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/texture.jpg"),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover)),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                         
                        }, // Image tapped
                        child: SvgPicture.asset(
                          'assets/images/close.svg',
                          fit: BoxFit.contain, // Fixes border issues
                          width: 40.0,
                          height: 40.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
              
                  Text('${this.title}',
                      maxLines: 1,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat')),
                  SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                  Expanded(
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: Text('${this.description}',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center))),
                  SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                ],
              ),
            ))
```

Also the description lighter gray has expanded scroll view inside. Basically I want the container to fill with height when there is text added, and when it reaches 200 height enable the scroll for text.

Parent:

```
Stack(
   children: [
        Positioned(
            top: 0,
            child: DataBox()
       )
    ])
```

Comment: you can use `Container(width: double.infinity, height: double.infinity)`

Comment: @Autocrab, I am getting `Failed assertion: line 1877 pos 12: 'hasSize': is not true.` and nothing works when I added your line.

Comment: Could you please add full code of the container and its content? I'm not sure if I understood the question. You want it to adjust height so that it is not bigger than `200` and when the text is longer than that, you want it to be scrollable?

Comment: @FirentisTFW Yes, exactly like this, ill add more code.

Comment: @squnk Have you tried the solution I proposed?

Comment: @FirentisTFW, yes doesn't seem to work, the text is overflowing to right side.

Comment: Well, is the dynamic height working? I though that was the main question, I didn't check the rest of your code? But anyway, I don't see any overflow. Are you sure you tried my solution? Where do you see the text overflowing? I updated the answer because I replaced the images paths for test purposes - now it has your paths again.

Comment: @FirentisTFW, I think the height works, but everything thats inside is overflowing to right side instead of adding text below and adding more height. https://i.imgur.com/WxzqQan.png

Comment: Hmm, it does become scrollable in my case. Can you show the full screenshot?

Comment: Can you provide the final result image?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ConstrainedBox` and `IntrinsicHeight`. The latter will force `Column` in your widget to size itself so that it takes least available space (not less than 100.0 because of constraints placed above).

Just bear in mind that `IntrinsicHeight` is relatively expensive class so performance of your app might not be that good if you have a lot of complicated object that make use of it.

```
ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minHeight: 100,
          maxHeight: 200,
          minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        ),
        child: DecoratedBox(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                spreadRadius: 5,
                blurRadius: 7,
                offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
              ),
            ],
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/images/texture.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {}, // Image tapped
                        child: SvgPicture.asset(
                          'assets/images/close.svg',
                          fit: BoxFit.contain, // Fixes border issues
                          width: 40.0,
                          height: 40.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Text('${this.title}',
                      maxLines: 1,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat')),
                  SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                  Expanded(
                      child:
                          SingleChildScrollView(child: Text('${this.description}', textAlign: TextAlign.center))),
                  SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your **Stack** with **Container** widget give that Container the size you want